# Java keeps displaying some loops if user is required to enter input

Tags: java, loops, random, input

This problem has been bugging me for a while, there's no "error" but for some reason whenever my code has something like: `JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name:");`, in the java console it keeps looping some crap like:

```
01:03.31 76[dbg] CShellExtClassFactory::CShellExtClassFactory()
01:03.31 77[dbg] CShellExtClassFactory::QueryInterface()
01:03.31 78[dbg] CShellExtClassFactory::CreateInstance()
01:03.31 79[dbg] CShellExt::CShellExt()
```

It starts looping this as soon as that is called and it doesnt stop after input has been entered. This doesn't happen on my other machines. Is this something in the newer Java versions or is it something computer related? I tried looking it up, found some other people with similar problems but no solutions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java displays some text every 5 seconds (on a loop)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804439/java-displays-some-text-every-5-seconds-on-a-loop)